# Python 3 web scraper extremely simple not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I am working through a book "The Self-taught programmer" and am having trouble with some python code. I get the program to run without any errors. The problem is that there is no output whatsoever.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request\
            .urlopen(self.site)
        html = r.read()
        parser = "html.parser"
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
        for tag in sp.find_all("a"):
            url = tag.get("href")
            if url is None:
                continue
            if "html" in url:
                print("\n" + url)

news = "https://news.google.com/"
Scraper(news).scrape()
```

Answer (score 4):

Look at the last "if" statement. If there's no text "html" in the url, nothing gets printed. Try removing that and un-indenting:

```
class Scraper:
    def __init__(self, site):
        self.site = site

    def scrape(self):
        r = urllib.request\
            .urlopen(self.site)
        html = r.read()
        parser = "html.parser"
        sp = BeautifulSoup(html, parser)
        for tag in sp.find_all("a"):
            url = tag.get("href")
            if url is None:
                continue
            print("\n" + url)
```

Comment: Now I get no module name urlib??

Comment: `urllib` is a native lib in reasonably new pythons. You could try installing it `pip install urllib`, but I don't think that's even possible unless your python is very old. Could you post the entire error/traceback? Maybe on pastebin so it's readable?

Comment: Or run `python3 myfile.py` if you haven't upgraded to a later version of Python (`python -v` will show you the version).